# How can I declare a route taking these two parameters in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am pretty new in Laravel and I have the following problem.

I have to declare a route that handle requests like this:

```
http://laravel.dev/activate?email=myemail@gmail.com&token=eb0d89ba7a277621d7f1adf4c7803ebc
```

So basically it have to handle a `GET` request toward the `/activate` resource with two get parameters `email` and `token`.

How can I correctly declare this route? Then I only have to create the related controller method that takes these two parameter?

Comment: `Route::get("/activate/{parameter1}/{parameter2}", "Controller@getMethod");`, then `public function getMethod($parameter1, $parameter2){ ... };` https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters For more info. Keep in mind that `Route` parameters are **not** the same as `GET` parameters (ie those in the Query String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `routes.php` (Laravel < 5.3) or `web.php` (Laravel 5.4+):

```
Route::get('/activate', [ 'as' => 'activate', function()
{
    return app()->make(App\Http\Controllers\ActivateController::class)->callAction('activate', $parameters = [ 'email' => request()->email, 'token' => request()->token ]);
}]);
```

So we are instantiating the ActivateController class and calling the method 'activate' which is the first argument, then supplying a list of parameters the method receives in the form of an array.

```
public function activate($email, $token)
{
    echo "Email: $email"; // myemail@gmail.com
    echo "Token: $token"; // eb0d89ba7a277621d7f1adf4c7803ebc
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: This is really bad practice as it makes it impossible to cache the routes. 
Also, the injection of the parameters seems like a ton of code replication, i think this answer is misguiding the OP to perform bad practices.

Please just use ```Route::get('/activate', ['as' => 'activate', 'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\ActivateController@activate']);```

Then use ```$email = request()->input('email');``` & ```$token = request()->input('token');``` in your controller, it will make your life a lot easier by just doing what laravel.com/docs says.... Also you have two answers in the same question

Answer (score 4):

To pass the parameters as query parameters you can get them in the request object that's you can inject into your controller method:

**Route**

```
Route::get('/activate', 'YourController@controllerMethod');
```

**Controller**

```
public function controllerMethod(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $code = $request->input('code');
}
```

In addition you could also pass a 2nd parameter to `input` to use as a default value if either one of those aren't there.

Comment: Can I specify the parameters in the route instead retrieve these parameter from the Request object=

Comment: You can't specify them in the route definition without injecting them into the controller.  You can access them in the request object by `$request->only('email', 'code');` giving you a 2 item array as `['email' => 'youremail@mail.com', 'code' => 'somecode']` if `email` or `code` isn't in the request it will just leave it out of the array or if non exist you'll get an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use URL rewriting (Pretty URL) simply declare the route as:

```
Route::get('/activate','YourController@yourFunction');
```

and check for token and email in the controller as:

```
if(Input::has('email') && Input::has('token))
{
  //YOUR CODE
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with URL rewriting? an I specify the params into the route and then passing it to the controller method?

Comment: When I say URL rewriting I mean your url will look like:
http://laravel.dev/activate/myemail@gmail.com/eb0d89ba7a277621d7f1adf4c7803ebc

If you want to use this approach:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42539104/2952213 this is your answer.

Comment: Like what? It seems that your message is incomplete

Answer (score 0):

The route would be like this:

```
Route::get('account/email/validate', 'AccountsController@validateEmail')->name('account.validate.email');
```

The controller method would be like the following:

```
public function validateEmail()
{
    // request()->email
    // request()->token
}
```

To generate the URL with the query string you must do the following:

```
<a href="<?= route('account.validate.email', ['email' => $email, 'token' => $token]) ?>">
```

Or you can just hardcode it as well.

Comment: No I can't use URI like "/activate/{email}/{token}". I need to use the URL with the GET parameter using the ?param=value as specifified in my post

Answer (score -1):

Route:

```
Route::get('/activate/{email}/{token}', [ 'uses' => 'ActivationController@activate', 'as' => 'activate' ]);
```

Controller:

`ActivationController.php`

```
public function activate($email, $token)
{
    // $email would be 'myemail@gmail.com'
    // $token would be 'eb0d89ba7a277621d7f1adf4c7803ebc'
    // do stuff...
}
```

Or if you must use query params:

Route:

```
Route::get('/activate', [ 'uses' => 'ActivationController@activate', 'as' => 'activate' ]);
```

Controller:

```
public function activate(Request $request)
{
    if ( $request->has('email') && $request->has('token') )
    {
        $email = $request->email;
        $token = $request->token;
    }
}
```

Comment: No I can't use URI like "/activate/{email}/{token}". I need to use the URL with the GET parameter using the ?param=value as specifified in my post

Answer (score -1):

You will actually use ONE of the two features. You do not have to use both features at once.
My suggestion is to use only the routes.
Example:

```
<?php Router::connect(
'/activate/:email/:token',
['controller' => 'Accounts', 'action' => 'activate'],
['email' => '.*', 'token' => '.*']); ?>
```

Then you will use the following url: your-site.com/accounts/activate/your-email@email.com/your-token

The routes codes must be placed in /config/routes.php

More details in: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: I need to use the GET parameter declared by ?paramName=value

Comment: That's the same. And still have the advantage of using friendly url ...

Comment: You can expand this idea to: / controler / whatever / you / want
This way the system already gives you the data in the controller ready to be used.
Example:
Router :: connect ('/ activate /: p1 /: p2 /: p3 /: p4' ...)
The limit is your imagination, and code optimization is unmatched.